# Has Google code any option to download the code as an archive?

Tags: google-code

In GitHub I can download any project's code as an archive:

[image]

Has Google code any such option to download the code as an archive?

I know that I can use http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/ but I am wondering whether I have missed some feature on the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google code has no option to download the code as an archive.